# sort vector based on another partial matching vector

Tags: r, match

I have two character vectors A and B.  Most of A has matching strings in B, matched by the first 6 characters.
A strings always end with 'd', and B strings always ends with 'z'.  I'd like to sort B based on A, and put any non-matches in C.

Original data:

```
A <- c("ABCD01d", "DEFG10d", "ZYXW43d")
B <- c("ABCD01z", "ZYXW43z", "DEFG10z", "DFGS88z")
```

I'd like to end up with:

```
A <- c("ABCD01d", "DEFG10d", "ZYXW43d")
B <- c("ABCD01z", "DEFG10z", "ZYXW43z")
C <- c("DFGS88z")
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you attempted anything yourself? Please show what you have been trying and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
m <- match(substr(B,1,6), substr(A,1,6))
B[na.exclude(m)]
#[1] "ABCD01z" "DEFG10z" "ZYXW43z"
B[is.na(m)]
#[1] "DFGS88z"
```

Comment: Yep, I can't see a much simpler way. `intersect` and other functions which suggest themselves are all calling `match` under the hood anyway.